# boost fibers work_stealing barrier causes segfault

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, fibers

This is a completed version of an example I found somewhere in the boost docs on how to spawn worker threads to use with fibers work_stealing algo.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <boost/fiber/all.hpp>

int main() {
    size_t count = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
    boost::fibers::barrier b{count};
    for(int i=0;i<count;i++) {
        new std::thread([&b, &count] {
            boost::fibers::use_scheduling_algorithm<boost::fibers::algo::work_stealing>(count);
            b.wait();
        });
    }
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));
    return 0;
}
```

This causes a segfault most of the time and I don't understand why.

Here the cmake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

set(VERSION 1_68_0)
set(BOOST_ROOT /home/User/boost_${VERSION})

find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS fiber)
find_package(Threads)

include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable(test test.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT})
```

I am running Fedora 28 and built Boost from source with gcc 8.1.1 and didn't install it. The project is built with the same compiler. (libc++ isn't installed anywhere.) I get the same behaviour with git branches master and develop as well as 1_67_0.
I feel like I'm missing something obvious here.

Comment: Does the original sample also have the same crash? The stacktrace consistently reports: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/cs6QNZ42B5/ for me

Comment: the original example is the bottom one here: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/fiber/doc/html/fiber/worker.html It causes the same crash, yea. It depends on the thread count btw. sometimes it goes through with 2 threads so it probably really is a race condition.

Comment: I moved all sorts of variables around, tested a lot of different configurations of this. They always result in the same segfault. Only if the scheduling_algorithm is set tho.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug that will be fixed in branch develop.
The problem is that the registration of the work-stealing algos at the internal container is not properly synchronized.
Your example would look like:

```
size_t count = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
for(size_t i=1;i<count;i++) {
    new std::thread([&count] {
        boost::fibers::use_scheduling_algorithm<boost::fibers::algo::work_stealing>(count);
    });
}
boost::fibers::use_scheduling_algorithm<boost::fibers::algo::work_stealing>(count);
```

Comment: So I will not need to wait on some kind of barrier in the future at all when spinning up the threads? I have no issue with working straight from the develop branch. Is there any timeline on when this will be implemented?

Comment: barrier is no longer required -right. the synchronization is done inside `work_stealing` - please note to spawn the worker-threads first.  the fix is already pushed and will be part of the next boost release (boost-1.69.0 should be released at the end of this year).

Comment: of course, I would need to spawn the workers first if it syncs itself now :) many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've found another [example](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/fiber/examples/work_stealing.cpp) which uses [thread_barrier.hpp](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/fiber/examples/thread_barrier.hpp) from the examples folder instead of the [boost::fibers::barrier](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/fiber/doc/html/fiber/synchronization/barriers.html).
Everything else the same it works like charm.
This means that despite the documentation stating "The fiber synchronization objects provided by this library will, by default, safely synchronize fibers running on different threads." [(source)](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/fiber/doc/html/fiber/synchronization.html) they are not in fact threadsafe.  I now recognize that it is never actually stated that these are threadsafe but I still think this (combined with the [example](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/fiber/doc/html/fiber/worker.html) at the bottom I initially worked from) is very misleading. If you pay very close attention and assume that every single word was placed deliberately you could see through this unintentional deception.